# Angularjs, browser refresh (ctrl-F5), object injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, treeview, breeze

1. Angularjs+ breeze, I use a recursive function to display user treeview
2. data structure: user: {id, name, supervisor}
3. user A is B's supervisor, user B is C's supervisor. expect treeview display: A<-B<-C
4. the first time I load the page, treeview display correctly; however after refreshing the browser (ctrl-F5), it display A<-B, missing C.

I use F12 to view object, result below:
(4-1) When expanding $scope.auth.user (user A), it show user B, when expanding B, it shows user C.

(4-2) When I console.log print $scope.auth.user.supervisor.name, it prints B

(4-3) When I console.log print $scope.auth.user.supervisor.supervisor.name, it does NOT print C.  <------this is the problem!!!

My question is: 
As (4-1) shows user C included, why (4-3) happen? and how to make (4-3) print user C?

---

the first time I load the page, treeview display correctly; however after refreshing the browser (ctrl-F5), it display A<-B, missing C.

**So the key issue is what ctrl-F5 do, and how it affect local storage, cookies, and injection**.

the code is like below, see ///.

```
    function showNode(user) {  //show each node, works fine

        };
```

/// current user, $scope.auth.user = C, whose supervisor is B, B's supervisor is A.

/// below are (4-1),(4-2),(4-3) in my post description

console.log("before showNode, OK, $scope.auth.user: ", $scope.auth.user);
///(4-1) when press F12, it can expand to user A, then can expand to user B, then can expand to user C. it works fine.

console.log("before showNOde, OK, $scope.auth.user: $scope.auth.user.supervisor.Name=", $scope.auth.user + ":" + $scope.auth.user.supervisor.Name); 
///(4-2)try to get user B, it works fine.

console.log("before showNOde, ERROR, $scope.auth.user: $scope.auth.user.supervisor.supervisor.Name=", $scope.auth.user + ":" + $scope.auth.user.supervisor.supervisor.Name);
/// (4-3) try to get user C, but fail.

```
        var temp = "";
        temp=showNode($scope.auth.user);              
        temp = '[' + temp + ']';
        console.log("temp=", temp);

        $scope.roleList = eval(temp); // angular js treeview: http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular.treeview
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code so we can provide better help.

Comment: I just posted the code. thanks.